# Why does my Flask App not work correctly on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, html, css, google-app-engine, flask

My portfolio site has been deployed using Google App Engine, and it mostly works correctly, but one of my pages on the website doesn't work like it works when I just type python main.py on my machine. The page features one of my projects that takes as input an Excel file and does some processing using Openpyxl in Python, and gives the file back to download in the new layout. The problem is when I deployed the app I cannot seem to upload the Excel file, because I get an error "Error 3: Please choose a file to process" which is an error I just made in HTML when someone didn't choose an Excel file, but this error happens even if I chose an Excel File. I made like a "Download Sample Input" which is a typical file you can use in the program, then you choose a method and in this case "Rentmeester" and then click process. Then it takes like a second then it is finished processing and then you can download the new file. The problem is none of the processing works and the project basically is broken when I deployed it on App Engine and I don't know why or how to fix it. I struggle to get appropriate error logs in App Engine as I'm new to it. Here is the link of the broken project: https://christo.appspot.com/automate.html and here is a video of how it is supposed to work: https://youtu.be/nmDz4SmaKXY also here is all the source code for my entire Portfolio site on Github: https://github.com/CGVanWyk/Portfolio-Website I would really appreciate any light into this problem I am experiencing.

I think it may be because not all of my libraries are working or isn't imported correctly, but I'm not certain where to see if all the libraries is imported right or pip install'd. I tried this tutorial online with no success: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

https://github.com/CGVanWyk/Portfolio-Website

The code in question that isn't working is under /Templates/automate.html + failure.html + successful.html + inputFile.html + inputMethod.html for the HTML, /static/css/automate.css for the CSS, and most importantly main.py and helpers.py for the Python and Flask code and app.yaml just specifies the Python version. I don't know if I needed to include anything else there. I just followed this tutorial to deploy to Google App Engine https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart

Expected: successful.html when a file is inputted and the method was "Rentmeester" and the process button was clicked. Also there must be a new Excel file a user can download named "BEWERKTEFILE_RENT_SEPTEMBER2018.xlsx"
Actual: inputFile.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that, maybe the problem could be that you're using App Engine Standard, and this way you can't write to disk as explained in this [documentation[1]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments), also I think the best practice is to use Cloud Storage to manage your App Engine files.

if this answer is helpful let me know.

[ 1 ] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. All I did was follow this guide to get my app on the flexible environment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart Just a follow up, is it still needed to use a lib folder now that it is on the flexible environment?

Comment: I didn't find anything on that but, I don't think it would affect to leave it there.